# Why was my dissenting viewpoint in a post about diversity censored?

Tags: discussion, comments, deletions

In a question about special lectures for the ICM, [the following answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/368467) proposed that a lecture on how to make the mathematical field more diverse be given. The answer contains some rather bold statements about the intrinsic value of diversity, the current lack thereof, and the causes of this, which generated substantial discussion. I myself made a comment of disapproval about the statement that a talk on diversity had no other place to go.

> "A topic ... with no obvious other place to go ..." Are you actually serious? Attention to diversity is all over the place. Every university has diversity statements. There's entire conferences dedicated entirely to women or minorities. There even special job positions for 'diverse' individuals.

My comment received over sixty votes, and it stood at the top of the post. It appears to have been removed, along with other dissenting voices of [Harry Gindi](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1353/harry-gindi), [RP_](https://mathoverflow.net/users/17907/rp), and probably others. I did not receive a comment about it being removed. What is the rationale for this decision?

Comment: On main, I wrote...To clarify: "No other obvious place in the ICM program." According to the fourth bullet point in the question, this kind of lecture could fit as an ICM special lecture. I stand by my argument that such a talk could help propel the math community to a better place, and could help mathematicians understand the current status, current initiatives, and research on what works. I do not think a "rebuttal" would be necessary, as the talk would be based on the published literature, and not what people feel we should or should not be doing. ICM can help legitimize this kind of work.

Comment: I had nothing to do with the deletion of comments, and I'm glad yours is surviving here, because it shows the division within the community. However, the deletion of the comments by Harry Gindi does not represent silencing of dissent. He deleted his own comments, as he wrote that he was going to do here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111634/discussion-about-suggestion-of-icm-talk-focusing-on-making-math-more-diverse-inc

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of Harry's comments (and of the existence of the chat).

Comment: Reminder to everyone that Patriot is an apologist for slavery and treason, and should not be treated as a good faith participant in this kind of discussion.

Comment: @NoahSnyder, as someone who disagrees with the premise of this question and downvoted it, does [this](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4671/why-was-my-dissenting-viewpoint-in-a-post-about-diversity-censored#comment23694_4671) belong in a meta question?  Presumably the answer, if the comments were removed, is that they violate community norms or site guidelines; it doesn't matter who made them. I wouldn't like to see *ad hominem* attacks become involved in policy decisions.

Comment: @LSpice: Generally I think that's true, but I make an exception for Confederates and Nazis who have no place in decent society.

Comment: I also think it's telling that this discussion is certain to have more overt white supremacists involved in it than underrepresented minorities.

Comment: @NoahSnyder isn't treason a good thing sometimes? Say a soldier who refuses to execute civilians in spite of a direct order is committing treason. Morally equating slavery with treason implies that good people should never question the state (or maybe you didn't equate them but then why mention Patriot's view on treason at all).

Comment: Noah Snyder, your comments (here and on some other posts) seem to me antifascist enough that I am uncomfortable sharing a forum with you.  I am willing to strike an uneasy peace with you by not commenting further in this thread if you will do the same (meaning your not commenting further in this thread also).  I won't even assume lack of response as agreement with this; I'll just be grateful for the lack of response.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman But it's fine for you to share a forum with fascists and apologists? Hypocrisy much?

Comment: In the linked chat, it was suggested that the comments were possibly deleted automatically as a result of receiving too many flags. The [help centre](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/flag-posts) offers the following vague wording: "In addition to bringing the comment to the attention of the moderators, a sufficient number of flags on a single comment will cause it to be deleted automatically. The number of flags required for deletion varies based on the number of votes on the comment, as well as the content of the comment itself." Can moderators confirm that this is what happened?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn : [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757) says that the number of flags needed to trigger deletion is 3 + score/3, rounded up, unless the comment contains certain keywords that lower the threshold. To delete a comment with a score of 60+ in this manner would seem to require a coordinated effort.

Comment: @Sayan, I respond with great reluctance: I want to share a forum with mathematicians and people who discuss mathematics, not politics and not the politics of exclusion.  Unfortunately, MathOverflow is rife with the politics of exclusion, and I am sad that it did not develop into the idea of inclusion that I once had for it.  Your remark is inciteful, not insightful, and I wish you would remove it.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Speaking generally, I share your viewpoint; I strongly agree with you that disregarding rules in order to extraordinarily punish someone is a way of making those rules irrelevant even when they would help, and often is counterproductive. That said, from the outside, your "peace" honestly looks like you saying "please shut up" to me, in large part because it came before you and Noah Snyder had a disagreement that would clearly benefit from both of you "peacing out". I'm sure there's more context I'm missing - e.g. those "other posts" - but that is how it appeared to me.

Comment: Some context: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3981/why-was-there-pushback-on-a-users-profile-image

Comment: @crispr: Disobeying an order is not treason; disobeying a clearly illegal order is a requirement of every soldier in any modern army, at the very least in the western countries (whether or not this is enforced is a different story). The "superior orders" was shown to not work as a legal defense at the Nuremberg trails.

Comment: @AsafKaragila but the treason referred to by Noah Snyder did not happen in the modern times I think. Also, laws are written by the state too, aren't they? Were the founders of the United States traitors?

Comment: To clarify I am not defending the confederates. I denounce their actions because I think that refusing to outlaw slavery and taking military action to prevent it from getting outlawed is immoral. I do not however think that treason is immoral per se.

Comment: @crispr I suspect one reason Noah chose to mention "treason" was to point out the contrast with the username "Patriot".  They are very nearly contradictory, independent of your moral stance regarding treason.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Hi Gerhard, I hope all has been well since the MO celebration last year. I agree with your sentiment that these discussions are 'ugly' and non mathematical, but these topics are inherently ugly and open discourse around them is necessary to collectively perceive them and decide if we should take action. Encouraging everyone to stay quiet on the matter (even in pursuit of peace) indirectly supports the status quo since it has inertia on its side, and the status quo is unacceptable to many people including myself. I also hope for civility, but rudeness is preferential to silence.

Comment: @NoahSnyder Initially, [this comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4671/#comment23694_4671) came across to me as (i) a harsh accusation, which was (ii) lacking in substantiating evidence. Finally, [Theo provided some context](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4671/cb=1#comment23705_4671). I think the discussion here would have greatly benefited if you included a link like Theo's from the beginning so that we all knew what you were talking about. In that spirit, is there any further specific context we should be aware of when forming our own opinions _vis a vis_ user "Patriot"?

Comment: @TimCampion: You're right, next time I'll link (and also not mention treason, since that seems to have caused a lot of irrelevant distraction).

Comment: @NoahSnyder: "Patriot is an apologist for slavery and treason" or, as Occam's Razor would suggest, someone who trolls people with a Confederate Flag avatar. Not something I'd do myself, but something I have seen people do and I can well sympathize with. Your summary is alarmist BS, and you knew this, which is why you gave no details and didn't link to the meta thread.

Comment: @darijgrinberg My bold guess is that people who find the flag offensive don't see the distinction you draw between (1) trolls who use the flag publicly, and (2) true believers who use the flag publicly, as a particularly useful or interesting one.  I would suppose that from their perspective, anyone who plants the flag in a public forum goes into the same mental box and it would be a waste of time to do otherwise.  Incidentally, do you think MathOverflow should be more welcoming to trolls than to the people they pretend to be?

Comment: @S.Carnahan: The question here is not how welcoming we should be to a certain person, but how interested we should be in a certain question. Patriot's question was obviously of interest to the meta community, seeing that it got 13 upvotes. I, too, think it is a valid question, which does not magically change just because it was asked with trollish intent. (Besides, it also mentioned RP_'s comments being deleted; RP_, unlike Patriot, is a long-time contributor with 66 answers.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg "We are what we pretend to be, so we must be careful about what we pretend to be." - Kurt Vonnegut.

Comment: Comments on SE are ephemeral. Complaints about deleted comments are a waste of time.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** I moved all of the comments that were not deleted by commenters to chat.  Your comment is restored [there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/111776).

**Older answer:** I'll start by mentioning some context for the benefit of people who haven't read the question.  Martin Hairer (chair of the ICM programme committee) asked a question about proposed topics for an ICM special lecture.  David's answer started with, "A topic worthy of a special lecture, and with no obvious other place to go, is ways we as mathematicians can make our field more diverse, equitable, and inclusive."

Your comment starts as an objection to the claim that the topic has no obvious other place to go.  David has clarified that he meant this in the context of lectures at the ICM, but let's assume this interpretation was not clear.  Your response was roughly that diversity is a widely-discussed topic in academia, or perhaps that there are already substantial efforts to increase diversity in academia.  Okay, but how is that a dissenting viewpoint?  You were only addressing a peripheral point in the first sentence, and you didn't come to any conclusion about the core of David's answer.

What would your dissenting viewpoint be if you chose to write one explicitly?

1. "I don't think this topic has a place in the ICM because people discuss it everywhere else"?
2. "This topic is not worthy of a special lecture because I like my ICMs to be research-only/non-political/devoid of discussion about social aspects of our field"?
3. "I disagree with the idea that we as mathematicians should try to make our field more diverse, equitable, and inclusive"?
4. Something else?

To return to the point of your question, it seems that someone who may have read between the lines of your comment chose to flag it as "harassment, bigotry, or abuse" and a moderator then responded by deleting it.  I don't know the precise rationale, but I approve of the deletion, since your comment is provocatively phrased, not particularly informative, and does not contribute substantially to a productive discussion.  The fact that it got 47 votes is not absolute protection against deletion, but it does mean we weigh our options seriously.

Comment: I had read the comments by RP_ and by Patriot.  I don't see what was so objectionable about these that they should be removed.   Removing comments that one disagrees with does not fit with my ideas of liberal democratic discourse.  I can understand if the comments were rude, or hateful, or distasteful, or ... ; but the comments that were removed were not in this category.

Comment: @Lucia The comments in question were borderline to me, and I am in fact still a bit conflicted.  On one hand, comments on MO are not really meant as a place for liberal democratic discourse, and the standard for deletion of non-mathematical comments is quite low, but on the other hand, the specific deletion of those two comments could give an impression of favoritism.  I am much more in favor of moving all of the comments to chat, because they are a distraction from the point of Martin Hairer's question, and of MO itself.

Comment: Thanks for that response.  Indeed it would have been better to remove all the comments to chat.  I agree that the bar should be very low for irrelevant mathematical comments, but the discussion there was not mathematical.  So perhaps different standards may apply?  In any case, I strongly feel removing comments of this nature often backfires and ends up alienating people.   Either political discussions should be avoided altogether (I would be very happy with that), or one must allow that others might have different/uncomfortable opinions.

Comment: I'd like to second @Lucia, and I think the real rationale behind deleting the comment was that it goes against the currently fashionable idea to introduce policies to specifically promote particular groups of people, and this also seems to be the reason why the deletion sparks such an amount of controversy.

Comment: Thanks for moving all the comments to chat.  Since this restores the comments of RP_, Patriot and others, it addresses all my concerns.

Comment: I think the next time something like this happens, the first move is a moderator moving stuff to chat.  I might disagree with the move,   but if the rationale is to anticipate a flame war and move it away from the post, I and others are more likely to forgive and even applaud such preventative action.  Deletion can still occur if needed.  I apologize to Noah Snyder for continuing in this thread, and am willing to avoid chat rooms where he believes certain of his comments are needed.  Gerhard "Trying To Restore Signature Humor" Paseman, 2020.08.13.

Comment: @Lucia I restored the moderator-deleted comments by hand.  Other deleted comments were not transferred.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman What, precisely, is "something like this"?  Why is Noah Snyder's name even mentioned here?  Your comments on this page and the corresponding MO page have been incredibly vague and unhelpful.

Comment: It is perhaps partially my fault that the moderators did not move the comments to chat, because I asked them not to in an email. I felt the comment thread was helping to make the case that the math community still has some reckoning to do about diversity, and I feared that if it was all moved to chat then many would never see it. However, I trust the moderators to know best, and I respect their decision today to move it all to chat.

Comment: Then delete them. I don't think you would appreciate my response.  I think I'm done here.

Comment: @DavidWhite The existence of that comment thread was one of the main reasons why I decided not to engage (I'm not saying I would definitely engage with a dicsussion in chat, but that seemed much more suitable). Although I can't help pointing out that the comment thread mostly made me feel like Mercutio, R+J Act III Scene 1

Comment: @YemonChoi:  Thanks for the Mercutio reference.  It would be wonderful to put that in a guide for newcomers to MO!

Comment: @DavidWhite Also, and I say this with kindness intended at heart, it is quite possible for me to despise the racism in e.g. the UK without being fully on board with the language of diversity that I see trumpeted by the younger revolutionaries in online maths communities, not least because I get a touch grumpy about being POCsplained to. Not that I view you as having done so, but just to put "the math community still has some reckoning to do about diversity" in some global context

Comment: @Lucia Thank you. For what it's worth, I must admit that my political beliefs probably lean a bit closer to Scott or Noah than to those who have disagreed with them, but mainly I wish that MO stuck to the things that might have a hope in hell of uniting us rather than providing another forum for us all to discover how much we disagree with each other

Comment: @YemonChoi:  Agreed!

Comment: @YemonChoi: Most of us have most of participation here about math, but that's not true of Patriot who has spent the majority of their time here doing racist trolling and very little doing mathematics.  I'm happy to respectfully disagree with you or Lucia and learn from your perspective, but as I said above Patriot is not a good faith participant who we should be seeking common ground with.

Comment: Although you have mentioned that the messages have been moved to chat, some users might have problem finding that room. (Especially since the room was frozen.) So it might be useful to include a link to the room which you have created: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/111776

Comment: @NoahSnyder I am 100% behind you.  I just want to point out the possibility that while the account Patriot has spent most of their time on racist trolling, it is likely that the human being behind that username has been doing more substantial mathematics through other accounts.

Comment: @StevenGubkin: I really don't want to speculate in that direction, but if that's the case then that's honestly much worse.  But I think that kind of speculation is pretty dangerous and usually leads to mistaken identifications, and if someone is using a sock puppet account inappropriately I trust the moderators and would discourage anyone else trying to do anything.

Comment: @NoahSnyder I'm not sure I agree that user "Patriot" has spent "most" of their time engaging in racist trolling. Yes, they initially had a racist avatar, but they seem to have accepted the mods' authority to do remove it. I also find their username to be unnecessarily politically charged. But when I look at their post history, I'm seeing on-topic, civil discussion for the past few years. So unless there's some pattern of making trollish comments and then deleting them (which would presumably be grounds for suspension), I just don't see it.

Comment: Moving the comments to chat has one inconvenient though: it destroys the information contained in the upvote of the comments. The only honest solution is to put back all the comments, without censorship, at their initial place. I do not believe in Carnahan's honesty, but I will change my mind if I am proven wrong.

Comment: @Joël I respect your commitment to transparency/free speech but I have long felt that the problem with comment upvotes is that there are no comment downvotes (this used to drive me crazy on academia.SE as at least one user was fond of shooting from the hip in comments, and attracting upvotes just by a "ratchet" or "diode" effect)

Comment: @Yemon. Yes, I agree. But this defect is partially solved by the upvotes of other comments with opposed views. This is why it is particularly dishonest in a case like this to censor the comments defending one point of view and not the comments defending the opposing one.

Comment: @Joel I tend to find this only works if people will leave such comments, and they may not. For instance, despite comments I have made in this thread, my **actual** response was mostly "will the free speech absolutists stop being jerks about this" or, for the old school MOers, "oh god Harry just exercise the option of not blurting out whatever's at the top of your mind". **But I did not think such comments would generate more light than heat** and indeed in chat it seems that Clark and Harry are having a much more productive exchange than would occur in a comment thread

Comment: @YemonChoi:  I'm sorry to see that comment.  And I thought my views made me "an old-fashioned liberal" (well, old anyway!), not a "free speech absolutist" being a "jerk".   (This is written tongue in cheek;  I take no offense at all, and I don't believe any was intended.)

Comment: @Joël I agree with what you say about the inconvenience of losing upvote information, but the alternative is having 100+ comments that have almost nothing to do with ICM special lectures on a page that is specifically about ICM special lectures.

Comment: @Lucia Glad no offence was taken, because I didn't view you as behaving on that thread like "a free speech absolutist", nor as "being a jerk". Doesn't mean I agree with you, of course :)

Comment: Just a note that in light of user "Patriot"'s [words](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4682/why-have-i-been-suspended-from-the-icm-chat-general-remarks-about-unwelcoming-b/4685#comment23833_4685) since I wrote [this](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4671/why-was-my-dissenting-viewpoint-in-a-post-about-diversity-censored/4673#comment23781_4673), I believe the situation has changed, and I now [consider](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4685/2362) user "Patriot" to be a racist / troll who, as @NoahSnyder has said, doesn't have a place in decent society.